# How can I know when a real file is closed/opened from/into a visiable window?

Tags: vimscript

What I'm trying to do is, when a window is closed(bw,bunload)/opened (NOT fzf, quickfix q:, buftype=nofile, etc..) resize all the other windows.

This code works but I was wondering if there was a better way or a command that I don't know of? Another option would be to build a list or dictionary and keep track of open/closed windows of visible buffers with real files (overkill?).

```
fu! s:WindowsHelper(...)
    if a:0 == 1
        if a:1 =~ '\v.*Command' ||  a:1 =~ '\v^\s*$' || a:1 =~ 'bufferEmpty'
            return 0
        endif 
    endif
    call s:ResizeWindows()
endfu!

augroup WindowsStuff
    autocmd!
    au BufEnter *   if bufname(winbufnr(winnr()))   == '' | call s:WindowsHelper('bufferEmpty')
    au WinNew * call s:WindowsHelper()
    au BufUnload * call s:WindowsHelper(bufname(winbufnr(winnr())))
augroup end
```

P.S Ive crashed a few times but can't fully blame the augroup WindowsStuff yet, I'm waiting for my next crash to look at the verbose file.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure to fully understand your question. Normally when you close a window, all the remaining windows will take the place left. Perhaps ":help equalalways" can help.

Comment: I'm doing a custom resizing of all windows when a window is closed or opened. Maybe I should look into getbufinfo() and if it's not visible trigger the custom windows sizes.